# Datastructure for undirected graph edges with constant time complexity

Tags: c++, performance, data-structures, graph

I have a undirected graph where the nodes are stored in a flat array. Now I am looking for a data structure for the edges. It should have constant time complexity for getting all edges of a given node. An edge contains two node indices and additional information such as a weight.

The only way I see is duplicating the data, one sorted by the left node and another sorted by the right node.

```
vector<vector<int>> left, right;
```

But I would like to prevent duplicating the edges.

Comment: what do you mean by "getting". For a given node (of Vnodes), the set of outgoing edges is typically O(V). you want to get all of these in O(1) time?

Comment: @RichardPlunkett It should be independent of the size of the graph, but of course, can depend with the number of edges. Please note that I edited the question to ask only for undirected graphs.

Comment: @Jarod42 This distinction doesn't exist, since the graph in undirected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you just want an [adjacency list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) representation.

In this representation, each node would store a list of all its connected edges.

For an undirected graph, you can have each endpoint both store the edge.

There isn't really a way to get the connected edges for a node in constant time without some duplication. But you can just store a pointer, reference or unique ID (which can be an index in an edge array, for example) to the actual edge, preventing the need to actually have 2 copies of it floating around.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, how an I push_back() on a vector of vectors with an empty inner vector? Is `edges.push_back(*(new Vector<int>()))` correct?

Comment: Just `edges.push_back(vector<int>())`. If you use `new`, you'll have a memory leak, because that `new` can't have a corresponding `delete`.

Answer (score 1):

Make a vector of vectors.

Each node will have a vector of all the nodes it has.

You should build this during the graph creation.

Comment: Okay, this is what I though of. However, I would have to duplicate my nodes for that, right? Since with a single vector of vectors can only get all edges for a node, where the node is stored left.

Comment: You have the nodes there as well, so no need for another vector.

Comment: I have, but I wouldn't be able to fetch them in constant time.